# What are the costs and benefits associated to having a permanent mission in UNESCO for North Korea?

Tags: international, north-korea

> North Korea has “unilaterally” closed its embassy in Angola, according
> to the southern African nation, in what appears to be part of a wider
> series of DPRK embassy closures around the world.
>
> The Angolan Ministry of Foreign Affairs said Pyongyang announced the
> decision to shut down its embassy in Luanda on Wednesday, though the
> foreign ministry did not explain the reason for the closure.
>
> North Korea’s announcement came two days after Ugandan media reported
> that the DPRK would close its diplomatic mission in Kampala to
> “increase efficiency” of its operations in Africa, instead
> coordinating bilateral ties from its embassy in Equatorial Guinea.
>
> Photos released by the Angolan foreign ministry on Thursday showed
> North Korean Ambassador Jo Pyong Chol meeting with foreign minister
> Tete Antonio.
>
> DPRK state media appeared to acknowledge the closure of its embassy in
> Luanda on Monday, reporting that the ambassador had paid a “farewell
> visit” to the country’s president. The article mentioned that Angolan
> President Joao Lourenco expressed his will to continue to develop
> bilateral ties, suggesting the two countries will retain diplomatic
> relations.
>
> Another article in state media on Monday stated that the DPRK’s
> ambassador to Uganda made a similar “farewell visit” last week.
>
> The news of the closure comes as Japanese media outlet Yomiuri Shimbun
> reported on Thursday that Pyongyang will also soon shutter its
> consulate in Hong Kong and “more than a dozen North Korean diplomatic
> establishments in Africa and elsewhere,” citing sources familiar with
> DPRK internal affairs and diplomatic sources.
>
> The Japanese outlet reported that “financial difficulties” are likely
> driving the North Korean embassy closures.

https://www.nknews.org/2023/10/north-korea-shuts-down-angola-embassy-as-diplomatic-closures-widen/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_North_Korea

It has been reported that North Korea is closing its embassies due to financial difficulties. However, I also noticed that North Korea has a permanent mission in UNESCO. How does North Korea benefit from having a permanent mission in UNESCO? I noticed almost every country has a permanent mission in UNESCO. What are the costs and benefits associated to having a permanent mission in UNESCO for North Korea?

Comment: Costs don't seem that great since it's in Paris, where they probably don't plan to close their embassy. Also, UNESCO missions are all in the same building, so it's not like they have to rent something for that, besides some accomodation for their personnel, which is probably co-located with the embassy staff.